# How to replace Inf values with NaN in array in Julia 1.0?

Tags: julia

I have seen online in a few places the solution

```
 a = [1 2 3; 4 5 Inf]
 a[isinf(a)] = NaN
```

But this gives me an error on Julia 1.0.1:

```
 ERROR: MethodError: no method matching isinf(::Array{Float64,2})
 Closest candidates are:
   isinf(::BigFloat) at mpfr.jl:851
   isinf(::Missing) at missing.jl:79
   isinf(::ForwardDiff.Dual) at <path on my local machine>
```

What gives?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As an additional comment. A standard function to perform this action is `replace!`. You can use it like this:

```
julia>  a = [1 2 3; 4 5 Inf]
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  2.0    3.0
 4.0  5.0  Inf

julia> replace!(a, Inf=>NaN)
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  2.0    3.0
 4.0  5.0  NaN
```

It will perform better than broadcasting for large arrays.

If you really need speed you can write a simple function like this:

```
function inf2nan(x)
    for i in eachindex(x)
        @inbounds x[i] = ifelse(isinf(x[i]), NaN, x[i])
    end
end
```

Now let us simply compare the performance of the three options:

```
julia> function bench()
           x = fill(Inf, 10^8)
           @time x[isinf.(x)] .= NaN
           x = fill(Inf, 10^8)
           @time replace!(x, Inf=>NaN)
           x = fill(Inf, 10^8)
           @time inf2nan(x)
       end
bench (generic function with 1 method)

julia> bench()
  0.980434 seconds (9 allocations: 774.865 MiB, 0.16% gc time)
  0.183578 seconds
  0.109929 seconds

julia> bench()
  0.971408 seconds (9 allocations: 774.865 MiB, 0.03% gc time)
  0.184163 seconds
  0.102161 seconds
```

Comment: This is a very useful answer. I typed my answer without thinking about the fact that `isinf.(x)` would allocate.

Comment: Yes, in Julia - opposite do e.g. R - if you need performance you usually will want to avoid allocation of a binary vector to perform subsetting. In this particular case the loop is faster than `replace!` in this case because we can avoid branching in the loop using `ifelse` and since the operation we perform is simple and `@inbounds` the compiler can significantly optimize its execution time.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for explaining. I'll direct readers to your answer, but leave my answer as it is, since it addresses the part of the question that wanted to know why `isinf` doesn't work on arrays anymore.

Comment: Your answer is the simplest approach in 90% of cases it is good enough and all you need to know, so +1 :).

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** For the most performant approaches to this problem see the excellent answer of @BogumilKaminski. This answer addresses the more general question of why `isinf` and related functions do not work on arrays anymore.

You are running into the more general issue that lots of functions that worked on arrays pre-v1.0 no longer work on arrays in v1.0 because you are supposed to be using broadcasting. The correct solution for v1.0 is:

```
a[isinf.(a)] .= NaN
```

I'm actually broadcasting in two places here. Firstly, we broadcast `isinf` over the array `a`, but we are also broadcasting the scalar `NaN` on the RHS to all indexed locations in the array on the LHS via `.=`. In general, the dot broadcasting notation is incredibly flexible and performant, and one of my favorite features of the latest iteration of Julia.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your entire array to isinf, it doesn't work on arrays, it works on numbers. Try this:

```
[isinf(i) ? NaN : i for i in a]
```

Comment: This actually creates a new array rather than updating the current array. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, your answer is better